# How to create an update to your plugin in the update site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2, update-site

I have a eclipse plugin which I want to distribute. 
I have made a feature project which I have added the plugin to. 
I then made a update site project and added the feature to that.

When I go build all and point to that folder for installing it works just fine.

But how can I push/add updates to the site?
Changing the feature/plugin version doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: How do you build your projects?

Comment: I am currently just making a update site project in eclipse and then adding my feature into it.